# Using excel tabs in formulas - increasing tab value

Tags: excel-formula

I've got a xlsx file with 21 tabs at the bottom arranged as follows:

Index, V1, V2, V3, V4..... up to V20

In the index column

```
A1: ='V1'!C$1 
A2: ='V2'!C$1 
A3: ='V3'!C$1
```

How can I programmatically increase the value that refers to the tab by 1 each time. I need to do this for a lot of spreadsheets so don't want to manually edit the cell each time.

So something like this:

```
A1 ='V1'!C$1 
A2 = (Value from A1 ['V1'+1])!C$1
A3 = (Value from A2 ['V2'+1])!C$1
etc
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` function.

```
=INDIRECT("'V" & ROW() & "'!C$1")
```

Drag/copy down formula as required.

See image for reference:

[image]

[**INDIRECT** function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) returns the reference specified by a text string.